# Why does using reflection to query a DBSet generate a query that includes all columns?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I use an anonymous type to select a property from an entity, the SQL generated is efficient and only includes the columns queried within the anonymous type.

For example:

```
dbContext.ExampleEntities.Select(obj => new {
    obj.Id
});
```

generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ExampleEntity_Id] AS [ExampleEntity_Id]
FROM [dbo].[ExampleEntity] AS [Extent1]
GO
```

However, if I use reflection to do something similar across multiple DBSets, the SQL generated includes properties of an entity that are not queried as part of the anonymous type.

In my use case, I am trying to query properties located in a base class which all of my entity classes derive from.

For example:

```
public class EntityBase {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I am querying the DBSets that contain entities that derive from `EntityBase` as follows:

```
dbContext.GetType().GetProperties()
.Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
.Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
.Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First().IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityBase)))
.SelectMany(p => (IEnumerable<EntityBase>)p.GetValue(dbContext, null))
.Select(obj => new { obj.Id });
```

But, a seperate query is generated for each of the entities derived from `EntityBase` and the SQL includes columns which aren't used in the anonymous type:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[DerivedEntity_Id] AS [DerivedEntity_Id], 
[Extent1].[DerivedEntityPropertyOne] AS [DerivedEntityPropertyOne], 
[Extent1].[DerivedEntityPropertyTwo] AS [DerivedEntityPropertyTwo],
... 
FROM [dbo].[DerivedEntity] AS [Extent1]
GO
```

How can I avoid pulling every column for each DBSet containing entities derived from `EntityBase` into memory?

**Edit**

I tried @Pawel's suggestion below and changed the cast to IQueryable, but that did not have any effect.

Comment: 1) If you need this only to query entities by Id use the `.Find` method. 2) I wonder if changing `(IEnumerable<EntityBase>)` to `(IQueryable<EntityBase>)` would make it work. I think that when you return IEnumerable EF will stop treating this as an EF query and just runs Linq to Objects on results. If you return IQueryable it would be treated as part of the EF query.

Comment: @Pawel - I do not need to query by Id -- the ID example was contrieved -- In reality I have other properties that I want to query, but I wanted to give something as simple to communciate the problem. I tried your suggestion regarding casting to `IQueryable<T>`, but it did not have the desired effect.

Comment: I'd guess it's because of the `SelectMany` with the `GetValue` which would be flattening all of your dbsets into a single `IEnumerable` which you're then selecting from. So the `Select` is not done in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I need by transforming the query to the following format:

```
dbContext.GetType().GetProperties()
                             .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                             .Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
                             .Select(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First())
                             .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityBase)))
                             .Select(t => ((IQueryable<EntityBase>)dbContext.Set(t)).Select(obj => obj.Id))
                             .SelectMany(obj => obj)
                             .Dump();
```

It's slightly less readable, since the `Select` after the last `Where` must be nested, but it works.

I was unable to get the linq provider to generate a SQL statement that is a single union across all of the `DBSet`s, but this suffices for my purposes.